# Why is IE not adhering to my column widths?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This has been driving my crazy trying to solve

Code: http://pastebin.com/rqyw35jG

First of all, I'm rendering in standards mode.
I have a table in IE, with width=100%, and all columns in the table with specified widths **except** the last column. The intended behaviour is for IE to size the final column so it stretches to the page. This more or less works. However;

Certain conditions seem to break the table widths and cause IE to go and size the table however it pleases.

1. The table contains a row which is merged across all columns AND
2. This merged row contains enough text to fill the whole cell AND
3. Enough text is entered into one of the cells whose column had unspecified width, causing the text to wrap.

When this 3 conditions occur, all the columns move slightly. The text still wraps and you wouldn't normally notice that the columns are the wrong size unless you measure them, or compare the page to a version without wrapped text.

Is this even supposed to happen in standards mode?

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Data" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SQLClient" %>

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>

<%

 %>

<!DOCTYPE html />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:500px;">egqwgw gqgqwgqg qwgqgqg qgwgqgqg qwgqgg</td>
        <td style="width:500px;">gqgqwgqg gqwgqgqgq gqgqgqg qgg</td>
        <td>If too much text is entered into this column, the column sizes will begin to change. wehwehweh hwehwh whhwhwh hwehwhwh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a gqwgqwg gqgqw </td><td>gqgqgqg gqgqg</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Columns only move if text on this line is filling out the whole width of the page. gqwgqwggqg qgqgqwgqg qgqwgqgqg gqgwqgqg gqgqgqgqg qgqgqgqg gqgggqg 
            qgwgqgqg gqgqgqwgwg qgqwgqgqgq gqgwgwgqg gqgwgq gqwgwgqgqwg qgwgqgqgqwg 
            qwgqwgqgqg qgwgqgqqg gqwgqwgqwgwqg gqgwgqgwg qwgqwgqgqgq qwgqgqgqg gwqgqgqg 
            qggqwgqg qggwqgqg
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code or it didn't happen! No, but really, can we see the code? A fiddle would do nicely.

Comment: Code added. You should be able to verify the issue by removing some of the text in the columns.

Comment: Please insert the problem code into your post, simply linking to code without posting it here as well is against Stackoverflow policy.

Comment: Please post an actual example (real HTML code) that demonstrates the issue. And define “slightly”.

Comment: In the example I posted, the width of the first column is 500px. When there is text wrapping in the rightmost column, the actual rendered width of the column is 640. When there is no text wrapping, the rendered width is 760.

Answer (score 0):

Your doctype is wrong and I'm not sure if it's throwing IE into quirks mode but it sounds like it. Remove the space and back slash: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Make sure none of that code is showing up before the doctype, too, cause that will throw IE into quirks.

Does this work in a modern browser or is IE the only one giving you problems?

Comment: fixed the doctype but it didn't make any different. I tried pressing F12 which allows you to test the page in the various compatibility modes. It's correct in Opera and IE9, however it's broken in both IE8 and 7 standards mode, as well as quirks mode. 7, 8 and 9 all render this page with different column widths.

Comment: @Trent - Then you'll need to put this online since most people don't use VB or ASP or whatever that is and it makes it easier for us to test.